# fbterm as standard console at login

Tags: terminal

Does someone know if it is possible to run [FBterm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fbterm) as standard console at login?

Comment: On which distro? Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/438950/how-do-i-make-ubuntu-start-fbterm-in-the-tty-on-startup or https://gist.github.com/zellio/5809852. YMMV

Comment: on the classic raspbian light

Answer (score 1):

On Raspbian (with autologin enabled), you will have `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf` which will contain the getty line you can edit:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear %I $TERM
```

If you replace it with

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/rungetty -u root %I -- fbterm
```

you will get the root `fbterm` terminal.

If you don't have autologin, you can create the file yourself (don't name it `autologin` though, perhaps `fbterm.conf` would be a better name) with

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/rungetty -u root %I -- fbterm -- login
```

That should give you a typical login prompt inside `fbterm`.